# Best Overloaded method match has some invalid arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two tables `deal_outlet` and `vendors_outlet`. I am trying to compare a list of `outlet_id` from `deal_outlet` table to vendor table but `.contain` method shows error has some invalid arguments. I really don't understand problem in this code.

```
public ActionResult Detail_of_deal(int id)
{

    var d1 = db.deal_outlet.Where(x => x.outlet_id==id).ToList();
   f_model.model4 = db.vendors_outlet.Where(x =>d1.Contains(x.outlet_id)).ToList();

    var d = obj.detail_of_image(id,ref model);
    return View(f_model);
}
```

Comment: If possible could you include the exact text of the error message. There are many places in this code that could be throwing many different errors for many different reasons.

Comment: it shows error exactly in this line of code "d1.Contains(x.outlet_id)"

Comment: ERROR : Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<repository.deal_outlet>.Contains(repository.deal_outlet)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\sidra\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\deals_for_you\Controllers\userController.cs 31 57 deals_for_you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the goal of the code you could try the following:

```
    public ActionResult Detail_of_deal(int id)
        {
            var d1 = db.deal_outlet.Where(x => x.outlet_id==id).ToList();

            f_model.model4 = db.vendors_outlet.AsEnumerable().Select(x => d1.Contains(x.outlet_id)).ToList();

            var d = obj.detail_of_image(id,ref model);
            return View(f_model);
        }
```

That should make `f_model.model4` a list of all the `vendors_outlet`s that have a matching `deal_outlet.id`

Comment: d1 is a list it does not have one single row so how could i fetch d1.id??

Comment: My mistake, misinterpreted the purpose. I have updated the example with something that should work.

Comment: your suggested solution give the following exception "Unable to create a constant value of type 'repository.deal_outlet'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Answer (score 0):

The Linq `Contains` method returns true if the list contains the *item* passed in. You are asking to see if a list of `deal_outlet` objects contains an `int`, which obviously it won't.

Instead of projecting a collection of `deal_outlet`s, project a list of integers:

```
var d1 = db.deal_outlet.Where(x => x.outlet_id==id).Select(x => x.outlet_id);
f_model.model4 = db.vendors_outlet.Where(x =>d1.Contains(x.outlet_id)).ToList();
```

But logically, that's the same as:

```
f_model.model4 = db.vendors_outlet.Where(x =>x.outlet_i==id)).ToList();
```

So it's not clear what you're trying to do.

EDIT

Based on your comments, I believe these are the queries you want:

> i am trying to fetch list of outlet_id from deal_outlet table where deal_id equal to id,

```
 var d1 = db.deal_outlet.Where(x => x.deal_id==id).ToList();
```

> Now want to compare this list to vendor_outlet table and fetch those rows where outlet_id from deal_outlet table equals to outlet_id in vendor_outlet table

Get a list of ID's to match:

```
var ids = d1.Select(x => x.outlet_id).ToList();
```

And use `Contains` to see if the list contains any of the IDs from the related table:

```
f_model.model4 = db.vendors_outlet.Where(vo => ids.Contains(vo.outlet_id))
                                  .ToList();
```

Comment: 1- i am trying to fetch list of outlet_id from deal_outlet table where deal_id equal to id, 2- Now want to compare this list to vendor_outlet table and fetch those rows where oulet_id from deal_outlet table equals to outlet_id in vendor_outlet table

Comment: my requirement is comparing list from one table to another table that's it

Comment: Exception: "Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'repository.deal_outlet'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: @Alina The next best way is to extract a list of IDs and use that in a `Contains` query. You can;t do it inline since the EF engine will try to turn it into a SQL statement and doesn't know what do to with the inner query.

Comment: This solution work for me Thank you so much @D Stanley